# innerHTML not working after installing Tailwind CSS in my NextJS project

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, innerhtml

I am trying to insert content into a div using `innerHTML`, but it doesn't work properly. It shows only the text as if it's being inserted without the tag. It was working properly before installing Tailwind CSS in my NextJS project. Right after installing it I am unable to show the inserted text designed with tags like h2, ol, etc.

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export default function Home() {
  const contentRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  useEffect(()=> {
    if (contentRef.current) {
      contentRef.current.innerHTML = '<h1>Hello</h1>'
    }
  })
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main>
         <div ref={contentRef}></div>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Isn’t that because Tailwind resets all styles and you do not add any classes to the `h1`, making it render like unstyled text? See: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight

Comment: Thank you Gabe. The link you provided helped me solving the issue.